# How to set alarm at exact time in KITKAT

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have set alarm to get trigger after 60 seconds. but the alarm is getting triggered after 80/90 seconds (But not exactly after 60 seconds). How can i set alarm to get trigger exact at specified time?

```
 //calling method to set alarm after 60 seconds
    startAlarm(context, 1, System.currentTimeMillis()+60000);

    //method defination
    public static void startAlarm(Context context, int timerType, long nextScheduledTime) {
            EABLog.d(TAG, " ~~~INSIDE START ALARM~~~~~ "+timerType);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_TIMER_TYPE, timerType);
            intent.setAction(""+timerType);
            PendingIntent pollPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    timerType, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextScheduledTime,
                    pollPendingIntent);
            EABLog.d(TAG, System.currentTimeMillis()+" ALARM IS SET AT "+nextScheduledTime+" TYPE :"+timerType);
        }


//permission added in Android Manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: Are you developing on kitkat?

Comment: if you are testing it on API 19, than i think you should try setInexactRepeating() as in api 19 all alarms are inexact.

Comment: Yes. I am developing on kitkat

Comment: The code seems to be correct but maybe you can be interested in the broadcast action [ACTION_TIME_TICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As docs say about **setExact** - The alarm will be delivered **as nearly as possible** to the requested trigger time. So it is not as exact as you think :)

Look at **public void setWindow (int type, long windowStartMillis, long windowLengthMillis, PendingIntent operation)** methods 3rd parameter - **windowLengthMillis**   The length of the requested delivery window, in milliseconds. The alarm **will be delivered no later than** this many milliseconds after windowStartMillis.
This might do the trick :)

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how it's used? Has it also changed on newer Android versions?

Comment: Now you have to use AlarmManagerCompat.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle + many things like removing an app from battery optimization list etc.

Comment: Android Clock app has a system permission, it is an exception for all optimizations, but on Android 10 few phones like Huawei or Xiaomi might block even the system Clock app.

Comment: But it says "setExactAndAllowWhileIdle " is restricted to number of times it can trigger in short time, yet for some reason Clock app of Google can wake up with 2 alarms set, one minute after another, and that's even though it's not on the battery optimization list in the "not optimized" section. How come? Anyway, I've made this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60079472/878126